# How to show values correctly on Core Plot pie chart

Tags: ios, swift3, core-plot

so currently I have a pie chart which shows the amount spent in each category that a user logs an expense in. This is using Core Plot. When I have 2 or 3 categories, the graph is fine and looks like this.

[image]

But as soon as I add multiple categories, the view gets distorted, like this:

[image]

Here is my code that decides this, and I can't seem to fix it.

```
func configureGraph() {
    let graph = CPTXYGraph(frame: hostView.bounds)
    hostView.hostedGraph = graph
    graph.paddingLeft = 0.0
    graph.paddingTop = 0.0
    graph.paddingRight = 0.0
    graph.paddingBottom = 0.0
    graph.axisSet = nil

    // 2 - Create text style
    let textStyle: CPTMutableTextStyle = CPTMutableTextStyle()
    textStyle.color = CPTColor.black()
    textStyle.fontName = "HelveticaNeue-Bold"
    textStyle.fontSize = 16.0
    textStyle.textAlignment = .center

    // 3 - Set graph title and text style
    graph.title = ""
    graph.titleTextStyle = textStyle
    graph.titlePlotAreaFrameAnchor = CPTRectAnchor.top
}

func configureChart() {
    var i:Float = 0
    for c in categoryTotals{
        if Int(c) != 0{
            i+=1
        }
    }
    let graph = hostView.hostedGraph!

    // 2 - Create the chart
    let pieChart = CPTPieChart()
    pieChart.delegate = self
    pieChart.dataSource = self
    pieChart.pieRadius = (min(hostView.bounds.size.width, hostView.bounds.size.height) * 0.7) / 2
    pieChart.identifier = NSString(string: graph.title!)
    pieChart.startAngle = CGFloat(M_PI_4)
    pieChart.sliceDirection = .clockwise
    pieChart.labelOffset = CGFloat(-1.8/i) * pieChart.pieRadius

    // 3 - Configure border style
    if i>1{
    let borderStyle = CPTMutableLineStyle()
    borderStyle.lineColor = CPTColor.white()
    borderStyle.lineWidth = 2.0
    pieChart.borderLineStyle = borderStyle
    }

    // 4 - Configure text style
    let textStyle = CPTMutableTextStyle()
    textStyle.color = CPTColor.white()
    textStyle.textAlignment = .center
    textStyle.fontSize = 15
    pieChart.labelTextStyle = textStyle

    // 5 - Add chart to graph
    graph.add(pieChart)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not specific to CorePlot, the issue is that the slices can and do get too small to contain the label.

Recommendation is to use a Legend, and only show the % inside the pie chart itself.

A good guide on using a legend is at:
[raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/131985/core-plot-tutorial-getting-started)

scroll down to **`Legen … Wait For It… dary!`**

Here is the example from Ray Wenderlich

[image: Example]